# OSX - Retrieve user id of logged-in user from a system service

Tags: security, macos

I'm writing a piece of software that runs as a system service in Mac OSX and cannot seem to find out how to get the 'active' user.

There appears to be APIs to iterate through the list of logged-in users and be able to tell from a value which one has the machine console... however I cannot find any documentation on these APIs.

Looking at `/dev`, it appears that the `/dev/console` device is owned by the currently logged-in user... however I have been unable to find any documentation to confirm this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Apple's [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1133.html)

- Require SystemConfiguration.framework

  ```
  #include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  /* .... */
  CFStringRef result = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  /* .... */
  ```

OR use the utmpx APIs to get a list of all logged-in accounts from which you should be able to get the necessary information...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getuid](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getuid.html) and [getgid](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getgid.html) to get the user's user id and group id. You can use [getlogin](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getlogin.html) or [getlogin_r](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getlogin.html) to retrieve a string representation of the current user's name. You can get additional user info with [getpwuid](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getpwuid.html).

As a side note, "man" is your friend. Whenever you're in doubt, consult the [UNIX Manual Pages](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand what you were asking. I don't think you can get the "active" user, because there is always the possibility that more than one user will be logged in at a time. If you want to do something for a specific user, you might want to create a per-user launch agent.

Comment: There can only be one person physically using a Mac at once.  Fast-user switching doesn't allow multiple people to have control of a terminal at a given time.  Nor does SSH, it gets you console access, but no GUI access.
getuid and the like will return the current user of the running process (ex: root)... 
getlogin appears to have the same behavior.